# method works in the constructor but not in the action listener

Tags: java, object, methods, action, listener

my problem is that the method "findChampion" works only in the constructor, and I need to work within the action listener for use in the textfield.
I think the problem was the champion object.try changing the method and static variables but did not work
Thanks.

```
private JTextField textField;
private Champion[] championsList;
private boolean first = true;
int previous = 0;
public Finder(Champion[] champions) {
    setBounds(1,1,795,365);
    setLayout(null);

    championsList = champions;

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(354, 5, 107, 44);
    add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    //WORKS HERE

    for (int i=0;i<championsList.length;i++)
    {
    if (textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(championsList[i].getName()))
    {
        if (first == false)
        {
        championsList[previous].removeChampion(this);
        }
        championsList[i].position(119,120,100,100,50,50);
        championsList[i].addChampion(this);
        previous = i;
        first = false;
    }
    }
    //

            //BUT DOESN'T WORK HERE

    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            findChampion();
        }
    });
    //


}

public void findChampion()
{
    for (int i=0;i<championsList.length;i++)
    {
    if (textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(championsList[i].getName()))
    {
        if (first == false)
        {
        championsList[previous].removeChampion(this);
        }
        championsList[i].position(119,120,100,100,50,50);
        championsList[i].addChampion(this);
        previous = i;
        first = false;
    }
    }
}strong text
```

Comment: Please define work/doesn't work: do you get a compile error? runtime exception? the code is not executed? etc.

Comment: unless there is some action, that code will not get executed anyway

Comment: no compilation errors,one is that the method does nothing

Answer (score 0):

You should use DocumentListener instead of ActionListener for JTextField. This is best way to look for changes that happend in TextField.

`TextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener{
      //implement necessary methods
   });`

Look for example here:
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html

Comment: Then you can create object of that class of yours and init it in constructor like MyClass = this;

than use
   MyClass.findChampion();